# Spartacus3.2 - Auth0 Logout Giving CORS error

Tags: auth0, spartacus-storefront, angular-oauth2-oidc

I am trying to logout with Spartacus Auth0. I have used "OAuthLibWrapperService" and logout method. Where it is clearing access token only. Can I know how can I redirect to Auth0 login screen on logout button click.
Also tried with "OAuthService" and logout method clearing only access token not able to redirect to Auth0.
Tried with "OAuthService" and revokeTokenAndLogout method In network tab logout API shows CORS error.
Any help on this please to fix logout?

Comment: I don't fully get the question. Are you unable to extend AuthService methods to do something extra (redirect) after revoking tokens? If so, how do you extend those services?

Comment: Thanks @MarcinLasak for reply. I am trying to logout with OAuth with service of "OAuthLibWrapperService" with logout() method. It is just clearing local storage but it is not redirecting to login screen. Can you please help on click on logout to redirect to login screen

Comment: If you want to login and redirect I would recommend using `logout` method from `AuthService`. It redirects to logout page. That kicks LogoutGuard which invokes logout and redirects to hompage or login (if it's protected store).

Alternatively you can use `coreLogout` from `AuthService` and once this method resolves manually redirect to login page.

Comment: It mean to use import { AuthService } from '@auth0/auth0-angular'; for logout?

Comment: AuthService from @spartacus/core

Comment: Thanks Marcin. It is working. But small confirmation https://DomainName/v2/logout is still giving CORS error even It was allowed origin in AUTH0. Is that expected? Or is there any fix for that? Application wise I am able to logout.

Comment: I can't answer that as I don't have much experience in Auth0

Answer (score 0):

corsfilter.oauth2.allowedHeaders=origin content-type accept authorization Check if this property is present or not